# Symfony2 configuration isRequired() is not throwing an exception

Tags: php, symfony

I have a configuration section thus:

```
->arrayNode( 'email' )
  ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
  ->children()
    ->scalarNode( 'fromAddr' )
      ->isRequired()
      ->cannotBeEmpty()
      ->info( 'Specifies the from email address' )
    ->end()
    ->scalarNode( 'subject' )
      ->defaultValue( 'The default email subject' )
      ->info( 'The subject for the email message.' )
    ->end()
  ->end()
->end()
```

The arrayNode() has addDefaultsIfNotSet().
The fromAddr child is required, can not be empty, and has no default.
The subject child has a default value.

My app/config.yml omits this section entirely at the moment.
I would expect Symfony to complain that the fromAddr parameter is missing.
Instead no errors are generated and the configuration array I get back from processConfiguration() in my extension contains the section with just the default subject value.

Any idea what I'm missing here?
Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to mark the arrayNode 'email' as required ?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal parser code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much  Yann Eugoné. You got it in one. The email child was missing its isRequired() call.
Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes.
Thanks again.